# Azure KeyVault generated certifcate is showing Not Valid in Browser

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-aks

Created a self signed certificate in Azure KeyVault as below with DNS

[Azure KeyVault Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUXXd.png)

Have added the certificate to Azure Kubernetes Service as a secret using secret-store-csi-driver and added to ingress

Problem is while opening the DNS in browser it shows certificate is not valid as below

[Certificate Not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLChm.png)

The Certificate is already added to Trusted store and shows as below

[Certificate Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3uhZ.png)

[Certificate Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzE4w.png)

Also, the certificate in browser is the one in Azure Keyvault certificate as evident from the validity date

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use self sign a certificate, your Operating System or Browser wont trust this Cert, [as it is self signed and considered insecure for the Internet](https://www.gerv.net/security/self-signed-certs/).

You need to use a Cert from a valid [Certification Authority](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-certificate-authority/#:%7E:text=A%20certificate%20authority%20(CA)%2C,the%20issuance%20of%20electronic%20documents) or import your CA root cert that created the cert into your OS or Browser. But every user need to so this.

A better approach is [Cert-Manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) ff you are using AKS. Cert-Manager can issue certificates from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?tabs=azure-cli) is a workflow from Microsoft for this.